# How do I sync Outlook Calendar with Automatic Replies?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, automation, calendar

As the title says, I want to calendar book times away from my desk (out of office) in Outlook 365, and have them sync with my Automatic Replies, so external and internal people get those Automatic Reply notifications. I don't want to have to go to File --> Automatic Replies and set a date range and manually turn AR on, when I have sporadic dates over a week that I am in and out of the office.

Once the calendar item has passed, I want Automatic Replies to stop.

Is this possible and how, please?

Answer (score 2):

As I know, there seems to be no option that could meet it directly in Outlook, and I found a similar idea in uservoice for Outlook, it's recommended to vote for it :

https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/18507883-provide-an-option-to-automatically-set-an-out-of-o

Hope the feature would be added soon.